# 500 server error when using cURL to connect to MAMP site

Tags: php, curl, mamp-pro

Been having problems using running curl (7.4.3) to connect to a third-party API through localhost (Mamp Pro/PHP 7). After some research tried to upgrade openssl so could use TLS 1.1 following instructions at http://www.grasmash.com/article/using-httpsssl-mamps-curl-osx

Now curl isn't working at all and despite upgrade openssl is showing up as version OpenSSL/0.9.8zd (via PHP info).

Any thoughts on how to stop curl now throwing a 500 error everytime I try to use it?

Comment: Please state the operating system, the version of cURl, the version of PHP, and which SSL library they are using (NSS, OpenSSL, SecureTransport, etc). You probably need to download/build/install the latest cURL. If its a PHP problem, then you probably need to download/build/install the latest PHP.